# Heroku database table primary key doubled itself overnight

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, heroku

I have this Django (v 1.8) app on free heroku dyno. For purpose of this post I am simplifying my app a bit, but essentially, this the model i use in my app.

```
class PartyGuest(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     reservation_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, null=True)


def create_reservation_number(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if instance.reservation_number is None:
          initials = instance.name[0].upper()+instance.surname[0].upper()
          instance.reservation_number = "{0:03d}".format(instance.id)+initials
          instance.save()

post_save.connect(
     create_reservation_number, 
     sender=PartyGuest,
     dispatch_uid="update_reservation_number"
 )
```

Users fill my form online, and are saved into this model, then they receive reservation number XXXYY, where XXX is the the id number in database, and YY are initials of that person (e.g. for "John Doe" would be "001JD").

So two days ago last user on my website had database id number equal 33, but next user (registered yesterday) has number 66. There were no new users between 33 and 66. I have no clue what happened. One possible explanation could be that heroku database had some kind of malfunction and doubled its contents, and then deleted them.

I am looking for a cause of that bug, as well as possible way to avoid it in the future. If you need more details please ask.

Comment: Not sure why this matters. The PK is an opaque number, which increases monotonically. Nothing should rely on it increasing at a certain rate.

Comment: Thank you @daniel-roseman , do you have any suggestion how to implement correctly a field in Django so that it would hold unique integer, that auto-increments with every object in model/table ?